# Canonical coordinate

Tags: coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Sorry for my broken English.

I'm a physics undergrad and quite poor at math. While reading a mechanics textbook, I've found something I cannot understand.

There are coordinates, $(q,p,t)$ $\rightarrow$ $(Q,P,t)$ which are canonical and
$H$ is a hamiltonian of $(q,p,t)$, and $\mathscr H$ is for $(Q,P,t)$.

This is to show  $\dot Q_{i}=[Q_{i},\mathscr H]_{QP}=[Q_{i},\mathscr H]_{qp}$  ([ ] is a poisson bracket}.

We can say that
$$\dot Q_{i}=\frac{\partial Q_{i}}{\partial t}+[Q_{i},H]_{qp}$$ 
$W$  is a generating function and $W=W(q_{i},Q_{i},t)$.

As $\mathscr H=H(q_{i},p_{i},t)+\frac {\partial }{\partial t}W$,

$$ \dot Q=\frac {\partial Q_{i}}{\partial t}+[Q_{i},\mathscr H]_{qp}-\biggr[Q_{i},\frac {\partial W}{\partial t}\biggr]_{qp}$$

$$\biggr[Q_{i},\frac {\partial W}{\partial t}\biggr]_{qp}=\sum_{k}\biggr(\frac  {\partial Q_{i}}{\partial q_{k}}\frac {\partial}{\partial t}\frac {\partial W}{\partial p_{k}}-\frac{\partial Q_{i}}{\partial p_{k}}\frac {\partial}{\partial t}\frac {\partial W}{\partial q_{k}}\biggr)$$
$$=-\sum_{k}\frac{\partial Q_{i}}{\partial p_{k}}\frac {\partial }{\partial t}\frac {\partial W}{\partial q_{k}}$$
As $p_{i}=\frac {\partial W}{\partial q_{i}}$,

$$\biggr[Q_{i}, \frac{\partial W}{\partial t}\biggr]_{qp}=-\sum_{k} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial p_{k}}\frac{\partial p_{k}}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}$$

I know the chain rule but what I don't understand is minus sign. Why minus becomes plus? Why does sign change? Please help!

p.s I'm not living in an English-speaking country so the textbook is not written in English.

Comment: Which textbook? Which page?

Comment: \Qmechanics Sorry the textbook is not written in English..

Comment: Are you talking about the minus sign in $[Q_i, \frac{\partial W}{ \partial t}]=-\sum \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_k}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial W}{\partial q_k}$?

Comment: If that's the case, notice that the poisson brackets are **defined** to have a minus sign: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket

Comment: I understand why minus sign is there but can't understand why $-\sum_{k}\frac {\partial Q_{i}}{\partial p_{k}}\frac {\partial p_{k}}{\partial t}=\frac {\partial Q_{i}}{\partial t}$

Comment: So in your most recent comment, you are confused as to how the left leads to the right?

Comment: \Aaron Stevens Yes.